# Fast import CSV file to postgre

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have file CSV with 1 000 000  rows and I need import this rows to table PostgreSQL DB, I need do it very fast as it can.

I tried to use generators and fsync = off, but anyway i had the same result

Now import time is 17 seconds, how I can optimize code or db to reduce the time?

My code:

```
    <?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

    require_once 'db-config.php';
    function generateString($length = 15)
    {
      $chars = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm';
      $numChars = strlen($chars);
      $string = '';
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
      {
        $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
     }
      return $string;
    }



    $fileName = fopen("users.csv", 'a');


    for ($i=0; $i < 1000000 ; $i++)
    {
        $firstName = generateString(15);
        $lastName = generateString(15);
        $age = rand(10, 90);
        fputcsv($fileName, [$firstName, $lastName, (string)$age]);
    }

    fclose($fileName);

    $sql = "COPY users FROM '/home/artur/Documents/Projects/test.com/users.csv' CSV;";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo "Done! ({$time} seconds)";
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Now import time is 17 seconds, how I can optimize code or db to reduce the time?

Comment: 1 000 000 rows in 17 seconds. Is that really bad?

Answer (score 1):

Drop all indexes and constraints before the `COPY` and recreate them afterwards.

Other than that, only faster hardware can help you.

Don't ever set `fsync=off` in production. Just don't.